# Match and $Matches in Powershell via RegEx

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a little issue with a Powershell project, I've been working on for some time now.

The basic idea is that six iPerf speed measurements will be executed.
A logfile is created to have some data which can be displayed to the user.

But there's some issue with the match and variable Matches in Powershell to display multiple values..

There's the code, I've been working on..

```
    $1 = (Get-Content -Path 'iperf3.txt' -TotalCount 398)[-1] # Fetch details about speed measurements for download
    $2 = (Get-Content -Path 'iperf3.txt' -TotalCount 796)[-1] # Fetch details about speed measurements for upload
    $3 = (Get-Content -Path 'iperf3.txt' -TotalCount 1195)[-1] # Same as above
    $4 = (Get-Content -Path 'iperf3.txt' -TotalCount 1593)[-1] # Same as above
    $5 = (Get-Content -Path 'iperf3.txt' -TotalCount 1992)[-1] # Same as above
    $6 = (Get-Content -Path 'iperf3.txt' -TotalCount 2390)[-1] # Same as above
```

**Output via Get-Content and TotalCount**

```
    [SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   313 Mbits/sec                  receiver
    [SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   312 Mbits/sec                  receiver
    [SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.11 GBytes   317 Mbits/sec                  receiver
    [SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   311 Mbits/sec                  receiver
    [SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.11 GBytes   317 Mbits/sec                  receiver
    [SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   312 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Afterwards, I use the RegEx and Variable to output the numbers before Mbits/sec and include Mbits/sec from this line of code..

```
    $1 -match '\d+\sMbits[/]sec'
    $2 -match '\d+\sMbits[/]sec'

etc.
```

I do variable Matches to validate that the Variable is **True**, and receive the output of 312 Mbits/sec, but nothing more.

Now this is where I cannot see the fault in the code. The variable passed and it's true, but I only have one **Value** as 313 Mbits/sec via Value.

I figured that I would see both **313 Mbits/sec** and **312 Mbits/sec** in the output/value prompt.

Did I do something wrong while using the match/Matches variable/function?

Any feedback and/or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) only ever reflects the results of the *most recent* [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operation - and then only if (a) the matching was *successful* and (b), fundamentally, only if the LHS was a *single string* - if the LHS was a *collection* (array), `-match` acts as a *filter*, returning the *subarray of matching elements*, and does *not* populate `$Matches`.

However, your command can be greatly streamlined:

- Use a *single* [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) call
- Use a [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call with the `-Index` parameter to extract the lines of interest (indices are `0`-based).
- Use the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator instead of `-match` in order to directly extract the substrings of interest:

```
(
  Get-Content 'iperf3.txt' | Select-Object -Index 397,795,1194,1592,1991,2389
) -replace '.+\b(\d+\sMbits/sec).+', '$1'
```

Taking a step back:

Instead of selecting the lines of interest *by fixed indices (line numbers)*, select them by *regexes* too, which allows you to use a single [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) call:

```
Select-String -LiteralPath 'iperf3.txt' -Pattern '\s*\[SUM].+\b(\d+\sMbits/sec).+' |
  ForEach-Object {
    $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
  }
```

Comment: Hi Mklement0. Thanks for your reply. I tried out the Get-Content, and it works like a charm. How do I select for instance 311 Mbits/sec rather then 313 Mbits/sec from the text file? Any neat way to do that?

Comment: After some testing with the text file, it works like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Pazia; my pleasure.

Comment: @Pazia, as for your question: To select only a fixed Mbits/sec value, replace `\d+` with that value (e.g., `311`) in the regex used in the `Select-String` command.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't do anything wrong it's just the default behavior for the `-match` operator and how the [`$Matches` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#matches) is populated.

Here is an extract from [Matching operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators) that explains very well how it works:

> It is important to note that the `$Matches` hashtable contains only the first occurrence of any matching pattern.

You have 2 workarounds, the first one could be using [`Regex.Matches` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-6.0) to find all appearances of the matched pattern:

```
$string = @'
[SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   313 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   312 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.11 GBytes   317 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   311 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.11 GBytes   317 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   312 Mbits/sec                  receiver
'@

[regex]::Matches($string, '\d+\sMbits[/]sec').Value
```

Note that, in above example, `$string` is a *multi-line string*, however in the example it **will be an array** since it requires a loop.

```
$string = @'
[SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   313 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   312 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.11 GBytes   317 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   311 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.11 GBytes   317 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   312 Mbits/sec                  receiver
'@ -split '\r?\n'

foreach($line in $string) {
    if($line -match '\d+\sMbits[/]sec') {
        $Matches[0]
    }
}
```

[GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867) proposes to add a `-matchall` operator to PowerShell, if you believe it would be helpful consider up-voting it.